# Proving a vector identity ∇ · (A × B)

Tags: real-analysis

this is my first post here :)

Nice forum by the look of things.

Anyway my teacher showed me this I will attach the link here:

It is page 2 from this link: http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/mp2h/VTF/lecture15.pdf

At 15.3. the pdf discusses: Products of Two Vector Fields:

When the article discusses the proof of (6) is that the full proof of proving the identity?

Essentially it is this:

I would like to prove: $$\nabla \cdot (A \times B) = B \cdot (\nabla \times A) − A \cdot (\nabla \times B)$$

And the pdf shows this: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla \cdot (A \times B) &=& \\
&=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} e_{ijk} A_j B_k \\
&=& e_{ijk}\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}B_k + e_{ijk} A_j \frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x_i} \\
&=& B_k e_{kij} \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i} - A_j e_{jik}\frac{\partial B_k}{\partial x_i}
\end{eqnarray*}

(It is a lot easier on the pdf)

It just seems that the proof unfinished and doesn't show how it gets back to the form of:
$$B \cdot (\nabla \times A) − A \cdot (\nabla \times B)$$

Also if anyone knows can the letters A and B be exchanged by any letters say C and D for example?

Thanks if anyone read this and can help.

-nomad609

Comment: I put forth some edits let me know if that's fine

Comment: Also the only thing that is missing is just to use the reverse of the definitions to rewrite this as a product, but the "proof" is complete

Comment: The proof is complete in the sense that it remains only to state that the final form is the same as the desired sum of dot products. Yes, certainly the letters can be exchanged.

Comment: @Triatticus Thank you for your help, sorry about the sloppy code.

Comment: @Triatticus I kind of see what you are saying. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No problem, if you are familiar with LaTeX it makes life easier here, for future reference  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you very much for your post. Just a couple of questions please, I'd like to understand this better. Is there no further working out needed to demonstrate, that the last line is equal to this: B⋅(∇×A)−A⋅(∇×B).   I am slightly unaware of the importance of A and B, are they just particular vector fields - hence why they can be exchanged? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Triatticus yep definitely need to brush up on my latex thank you :) Can I rep you and Omnom somehow? :)

Comment: @Triatticus  Sorry to bother you but could I pose you my queries too please? "I'd like to understand this better. Is there no further working out needed to demonstrate, that the last line is equal to this: B⋅(∇×A)−A⋅(∇×B). I am slightly unaware of the importance of A and B, are they just particular vector fields - hence why they can be exchanged? Thanks again :)"

Comment: There are a lot of things at play in the last line, for one the object $e_{ijk}$ is known as the Levi-Civita tensor or permutation symbol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) it is used in definitions of the cross product like $A \times B = e_{ijk} \hat{e}_i A_j B_k$ where the $\hat{e}_i$ is the i-th unit vector

Comment: @Triatticus thank you again :)

Comment: Can I ask you guys - what prior knowledge is required do you feel to be better at answering these proof types, I endeavour to answer the other proof types on the article, Thank you.

Comment: You can look up two terms, Ricci calculus which handles index notation like this, and there is such a term as index gymnastics. Both deal with these tensor objects and indices

Comment: No problem, this is standard notation in fields like quantum field theory and relativity so I got use to manipulating indices

Comment: @Triatticus Awesome will definitely look at this. Thank you Triatticus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\pars{\vec{A}\times\vec{B}} & =
\sum_{i}\partiald{\pars{\vec{A}\times\vec{B}}_{i}}{x_{i}} =
\sum_{i}\partiald{}{x_{i}}\sum_{jk}\epsilon_{ijk}A_{j}B_{k} =
\sum_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijk}\,\partiald{A_{j}}{x_{i}}\,B_{k} +
\sum_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijk}\, A_{j}\,\partiald{B_{k}}{x_{i}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k}\pars{\sum_{ij}\epsilon_{kij}\,\partiald{}{x_{i}}\,A_{j}}B_{k} -
\sum_{j}\pars{\sum_{ik}\epsilon_{jik}\,\partiald{}{x_{i}}\,B_{k}}A_{j}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k}\pars{\nabla\times\vec{A}}_{k}B_{k} -
\sum_{j}\pars{\nabla\times\vec{B}}_{j}A_{j} =
\bbx{\vec{B}\cdot\nabla\times\vec{A} - \vec{A}\cdot\nabla\times\vec{B}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, clarifies a lot more. Thanks Felix :)

Comment: Thanks $\left({\Huge \bullet}\qquad{\Huge \bullet} \atop {\Huge{\mid \atop \smile}}\right)$. We have to be careful with indexes $i,\ j,\ k$.

Comment: Hey Felix can I ask you if we do as what Dr.MV said below and use the Levi-Civita symbol then would your answer be fully written in terms of Cartesianally?

Comment: Hi Felix, sorry to come back to this so late, but when you express the sigma symbol with say "i" below it what does that mean, is that the  e(ijk) that you are expressing hear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @nomad609 $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita Symbol ( $\mathbf{LCS}$ ). I don't see any relation to a $\sigma$ symbol. $\color{#88f}{\texttt{@Dr. MV}}$ answer is quite fine. The "approach with $\mathbf{LCS}$" is just more general and it exploits the cross product definition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be useful to remark that the Levi-Civita symbol, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ can be written alternatively as
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\epsilon_{ijk}=\hat x_i\cdot (\hat x_j\times\hat x_k) }\tag 1$$
>
> in terms of the Cartesian unit vectors $\hat x_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

Then, using $(1)$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon_{ijk}\left(B_k\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_j}\right)&=\hat x_i\cdot (\hat x_j\times\hat x_k)\left(B_k\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}\right)\\\\
&=\hat x_k\cdot (\hat x_i\times\hat x_j)\left(B_k\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}\right)\\\\
&=(\hat x_kB_k)\cdot \left(\hat x_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_x}\right)\times (\hat x_jA_j)\\\\
&=\vec B\cdot \nabla \times \vec A
\end{align}$$

> Evidently, this development differs from one that uses the Levi-Civita symbol by notation only.  It does assign, however, to $\epsilon_{ijk}$ a meaning as the scalar triple product.  And in doing so, this approach affords more transparency on the interaction among the indices of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ as unit vectors and the associated Cartesian components of both the "Del" operator, $\nabla$, and the vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ on which it operates.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Comment: Although may I ask in the second stage of your working out what is the relevance of putting x(k) outside of the brackets - is that by associativity you are doing it?

Comment: The scalar triple product has the property that it is preserved under cyclic reordering.  So, $$\hat x_i \cdot (\hat x_j\times \hat x_k) =\hat x_j\cdot(\hat x_k\times \hat x_i) =\hat x_k\cdot(\hat x_i\times \hat x_j)$$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Thank you Dr. MV that is what I thought. Thank you for your clarity. I just have a couple more questions if that is okay? In writing this in future, for the penultimate line that you wrote that is equivalent to: B⋅(∇×A)−A⋅(∇×B). Writing it in terms of the cartesian coordinates, is also a great way to express it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Would you also say that is the full proof required, I don't doubt that you have it correct, only that my prof seemed to write a lot more - although he likes to go off topic a lot :l

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what else to include.  Each step is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Dr.MV thank you so much for your help, I showed my teacher what you did and he said that it is correct, I will definitely practice this area for future. Thank you again :)

Comment: forgive me if I am wrong about this but should your final line not read: −A⋅(∇×B)?

Comment: ^^^ Where this follows from what you wrote.

Comment: Unless it is just how you have written the final stage, as it should be a X(Cross) between A and B I suggest?

Comment: @nomad609 The final version is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this question.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Whilst I understnad this a late post - I can't comment on Mark Viola's post - what is the purpose of working with i,j,k.

Comment: @HidekiRyuga I don't understand your question.  The Levi-Civita symbol is triple-indexed